# KeyError: 'Message' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am new to machine learning and I am facing this issue.

I have uploaded dataset with two columns and headings 'Message' and 'Priority'.

when I run this command,I get this:

```
'df.columns'


'Index(['Message\tPriority'], dtype='object')'
```

But, when I run this command, I get the following error:

```
X = df['Message']
ylabels = df['Priority']

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\anna\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Message'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-238deec7e797> in <module>
      1 # Features and Labels
----> 2 X = df['Message']
      3 ylabels = df['Priority']

D:\anna\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

D:\anna\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Message'
```

Comment: how did you load it ? It shows string `'Message\tPriority'` which can means it uses `\t` as separator and most functions use `,` as defautl separator and you have to add `sep="\t"` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess.

Line `Index(['Message\tPriority']` shows that this data uses tab `\t` as separator but standard `read_csv()` use `,` as separator and you have to add option `sep="\t"`

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t")
```